# Overlay graphics (aka adornments in VS2010) in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, add-in, vsx

I'm writing an add-in for both VS2008 and VS2010 and I'd like to have graphical enhancements that appear on top of the code (similar to Resharper/CodeRush). Doing so in VS2010 is relatively easy using adornments, however, how do I do it in VS2008? Anyone knows a good resource/article for something in that spirit?

I know that DXCore (CodeRush) allows one to do it, however, due to license restriction (I can't bundle DXCore with my addin) I am unable to do so.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up implementing it by myself.

The general idea is to make a transparent form (Winforms or WPF), put the adornment you want in that form, and then overlay the form at the position of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the editor was completely rewritten between 2008 and 2010 the technique for this is going to be totally different and it seems unlikely that now, 6 months after 2010 has launched, is a good time to start writing something for 2008, especially something difficult.

That said, a great source of sample code for editor extensions is http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx. This is from the VSX team and has been very helpful to me while working on extensions.

Comment: It is a valid point of view... However, do you have a user adoption/usage statistics of various Visual Studio versions? It seems to be that Visual Studio 2008 (which means also 2005) will still be used quite a lot in the next years. The companies I know, don't rush to upgrade their Visual Studio (especially since latest .NET version works just fine on Visual Studio 2008). I'll be glad to hear if you have any other insight on that.